# Not able to delete hidden space formatting marks

Tags: excel, vba

I got some data in Excel cell by some tool. This cell contains hidden space formatting marks. Each time I have to copy and paste that data into Word file then unhide that space formatting marks, delete them and again paste into Excel. [Hidden space formatting marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQUXZ.png).

I have also tried trim and clean function but am not able to remove them.

Is there is another way to do it directly?

Comment: Excel doesn't have "hidden space formatting marks". I suspect that what you have is a non-breaking space - character 160. Select the data in Excel, press Ctrl+H, click in the Find box, hold the Alt key and type 0160 on the number keypad then release the Alt key. Leave the Replace box blank and press Replace All.

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks for your help..also macro given below by Gray's Student is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must:

1. identify the "pseudo-space"
2. devise a method to remove them

First click on a cell containing the miscreant character and run this short macro:

```
Sub WhatsInThere()
   Dim v As String, msg As String
   Dim i As Long
   msg = ""
   v = ActiveCell.Text

   For i = 1 To Len(v)
      msg = msg & vbCrLf & Mid(v, i, 1) & vbTab & Asc(Mid(v, i, 1))
   Next i

   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

You would then run another short macro to remove them:

```
Sub fixdata()
   Cells.Replace what:=Chr(160), replacement:=" "
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Many thanks Gray's Student...By your macro all hidden space formatting marks in excel cell are removed...again thanks a lot ....